# How to play this trill?

Tags: piano

[image]

I don't know if I'm understand this right,

I trill between D and C with fingers 3 and 2 for at least the first bar? Start with the higher note which is D?

But near the end of the first bar I play the 16th notes B and C?

I can tap the B with thumb,

and the following C just means go back to trilling D and C but start with C to begin it?

---

UPDATE:
Advice and answers helped

Comment: Could you please add the title, composer and maybe even the edition this was published in? Some editions have an appendix on how to play the ornaments.

Comment: @Arsak: Czerny op. 599

Answer (score 8):

## Remember the turn at the end of the trill

The appoggiatura is trying to tell you the composer want you to have a turn at the end of the trill. You start on the C, go up to the D and then you have a turn at the end, similar to this.

[image]

Comment: That looks like the famous baroque trumpet tune, in which case the trill should start on A, not G.

Comment: Yes, a baroque trill starts on the upper auxiliary note

Answer (score 3):

If this was written before about 1830, then yes, start with note D. After, it's probably better to start with the written note. The alternative would have an acciaccatura written as well.

B with thumb is fine, although the timing may not be exactly semiquavers. Depends on the speed one trills at.

The following C? Please show.

Comment: I think OP asks whether the trill continues after the b-c, the 2 short notes.

Comment: @AlbrechtHügli - it's written in a confusing way, but I thought not. How could it?

Comment: Tim, I have my problems with questions like this any way. Is this questioning really a personal problem? Then OP should have been asked:  what research about trills and ornaments have you done? And then I wonder how someone will cope with next bars in this exercise .

Comment: @AlbrechtHügli - I understand what you're saying. There's no idea that OP (in this and many other cases) has done any homework of their own - which is a condition for asking questions here, I believe.

Answer (score 3):

This Ex. 74 by Czerny op. 599.

> But near the end of the first bar I play the 16th notes B and C?
>   I can tap the B with thumb,
>   and the following C just means go back to trilling D and C but start with C to begin it?

As you can see the trill between cd ends before the two 16th or better said the latter bc are included in the trill.

If you start the trill with d it will be easy to perform with 16th notes. If you begin with c (as written) there will be a triplet before the two last 16th.

You can practice both version, this is not so important.

You can also perform the passage in triplets or any duplets, don’t count to much, just let it flow, nobody of the audience will count the notes but they will hear and see when you are counting and struggling.

[image]
[image]

[Paul Czerny 1830](https://books.google.com/books/about/Vollst%C3%A4ndige_theoretisch_practische_Pia.html?hl=de&id=9UVTAAAAcAAJ)

Answer (score 0):

The little B and C at the end of the measure simply indicate that the last two notes of the trill should be B and C.  Without that indication, they would be D and C.  So basically, you replace the last D with a B.

By Czerny's day, it was normal to start the trill on the written note rather than the upper neighbor.

In other words, alternate C and D repeatedly, then the last three notes you play are B, C, and the D quarter note on the next beat.

Comment: I think Czerny used both, starting on upper, but also starting on the written dot. Things were changing during his lifetime.